# Getting/setting session cookie from Play Framework 2.2(Java) in Angular.js

Tags: java, javascript, angularjs, web-services, playframework

I'm just starting to learn Angular and decided I would build the backend API using Play framework 2.2 in Java. I've written web apps before in Play, but I only used Jquery and now im facing some confusions with Angular. I am trying to write an authentication service where i pass a username and password and then save the cookie in the Angular app. Here is my  code:

Authentication.js:

```
    (function(){

    var authentication = function($rootScope, $http, $cookieStore){
        var service = {};

        service.login = function(username, password, callback){
            $http.post("http://localhost:9000/login", {userName: username, password: password})
                .success(function(data, status, header){
          console.log(data);
          console.log(status);
          console.log(Object.keys(header));

                    callback(data, status, header);
                });
        };

        service.setCredentials = function(data){
      console.log("setting credentials");
        }

        return service;
    };
    var module = angular.module("listr");
    module.factory("AuthenticationService", authentication);
}());
```

LoginCtrl.js:

```
(function(){
    var module = angular.module("listr");

    var LoginCtrl = function($scope, AuthenticationService){
        $scope.login=function(){
            console.log("Logging in");
            AuthenticationService.login($scope.username, $scope.password, function(data, status, header){

                if(status == 200){
                    AuthenticationService.setCredentials(data, status, header);
                }
                else{
                    alert("error logging in");
                }
            });
        };

    };
    module.controller("LoginCtrl", LoginCtrl);
}());
```

when i submit the form in my app, I get back a 200 ok status, but im not sure how to get the cookie that play returns. I can see in the network request in the web console that the cookie. See the screen shot below:

[image: Network request]

I feel like ive been googling forever and I cant seem to figure out how to access the cookie. Also i've set the httponly as false with the folloing: session.httpOnly=false in my application.conf

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Also, in the image you can see there is a line that says "no element found" and it is linking to a page that is returned by a GET call to the /login url. Does anyone know why a GET call is hitting my server when I make a POST call?